# DataImportHandler setup with PhpMyAdmin-MySQL

Tags: apache, solr, phpmyadmin

I am trying to index a mysql database on phpmyadmin into solr.

**SOLVED BY @MatsLindh**

I have tried to find information necessary but no tutorials I have found deal with this setup.

MY DATABASE:
My mysql db is locally hosted and accessed through phpmyadmin. Here is the admin page.
[image: phpmyadmin admin ui]

As you can see I have a db titled solrtest with table solr having fields id, date, Problem, and Solution.

Now to link my db, the tutorials online were a bit inconsistent. The most consistent parts told me I would need to use solrs DataImportHandler and the mysql-connector-java. Another also mentioned a jdbc plug in. I have installed and put the .jar files here in my solr/dist directory.[image: solr dist file]
In some tutorials they have these also in the contrib folder but I have left in /dist.

MY FILES:
I have created a core titled solrhelp and made the following changes in the solhelp/conf files.

solrconfig.xml

```
<lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-7.5.0.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-extras-7.5.0.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\" regex="mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\" regex="sqljdbc41.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\" regex="sqljdbc42.jar" />
  <requestHandler name=" /dataimport" class=" org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name=" defaults">
    <str name=" config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name " /dataimport" class=org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="name">solrhelp</str>
      <str name="driver">jdbc:mysql.jdbc.Driver</str>
      <str name="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:8983/solrtest</str>
      <str name="user">root</str>
      <str name="password"></str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

the created data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8983/solrtest"
            user="root"
            password=""/>
    <document>
    <entity name="solr"
            pk="id"
            query="select id, date, Problem, Solution from solr"
        >
        <field column="id" name="id"/>
        <field column="date" name="date"/>
        <field column="Problem" name="Problem"/>
        <field column="Solution" name="Solution"/>
    </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

and the managed-schema.xml

```
 <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="pdate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  <field name="Problem" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
  <field name="Solution" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

My question to the community is rather broad and I apologize. I want to know what all I am missing before I attempt to post this db. I dont think I have edited my files correctly and I dont really know of a way to test them before I attempt to post. 
It should be noted that in the dist folder I have two verions of the jdbc and have both in my solrconfig.xml file.
Any direction to better tutorials or documentation would be appreciated.

UPDATED FILES
solrconfig

```
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\"
    regex="solr-dataimporthandler-7.5.0.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\"
    regex="solr-dataimporthandler-extras-7.5.0.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib"
    regex="mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib"
    regex="sqljdbc41.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib"
    regex="sqljdbc42.jar" />

  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

data-config

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8983/solrtest/solr"
            user="root"
            password=""/>
    <document>
    <entity name="solr"
            pk="id"
            query="select * from solr"
        >
        <field column="id" name="id"/>
        <field column="date" name="date"/>
        <field column="Problem" name="Problem"/>
        <field column="Solution" name="Solution"/>
    </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: You don't import "through phpmyadmin". You use the connection information to your MySQL server. There is no http involved. `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname` would be the string in your case, assuming that MySQL runs on the same computer as you're running Solr on.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you I have made that change in my solrconfig and data-config

Comment: No, you haven't - you're still referencing the HTTP port (and path) and you're still referencing phpmyadmin in the other location. Neither have anything to do with the connection string for your MySQL server.

Comment: I believe your referencing my data-config file for my issue. In particular: <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8983/solrtest/solr"
user="root"
password=""/>        Im not able to find the correct syntax I should be using currently my port is 8983, my db is solrtest, and my table is solr. If you could give an example I may be able to better understand @MatsLindh

Comment: @MatsLindh I have also put the most recent config files at the bottom of the post; also both my mysql server and solr are running on the same local server

Comment: Yes, but if you refer to the connection string I gave in the first comment - your MySQL server probably runs on port 3306 (the default), and has a database name - i.e. the database you want to run your SELECT queries on. In your example you've given the port to the _SOLR_ server (which is not where MySQL lives). You've also given the path as your Solr path (?) - `/solrtest/solr`. This should be the name of your database.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much @MatsLindh ; the first attempt to index after the port # change was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THIS PROBLEM WAS SOLVED BY @MatsLindh**

My issue was configuration syntax. Below are the corrected data-config.xml and solrconfig.xml

data-config

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solrtest"
            user="root"
            password=""/>
    <document>
    <entity name="solr"
            pk="id"
            query="select * from solr"
        >
        <field column="id" name="id"/>
        <field column="date" name="date"/>
        <field column="Problem" name="Problem"/>
        <field column="Solution" name="Solution"/>
    </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

solrconfig

```
<lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\"
    regex="solr-dataimporthandler-7.5.0.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\dist\"
    regex="solr-dataimporthandler-extras-7.5.0.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib"
    regex="mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib"
    regex="sqljdbc41.jar" />
  <lib dir="C:\Program Files\Solr\solr-7.5.0\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib"
    regex="sqljdbc42.jar" />

  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't import "through phpmyadmin". You use the connection information to your MySQL server. There is no http involved. `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname` would be the string in your case, assuming that MySQL runs on the same computer as you're running Solr on.

Pay close attention to the port number (`3306`) in the connection string and the `dbname`. It should refer to the values of your *MySQL* server and not your Solr server.